# Drupal 7 How to restrict the block from display for all pages where the URL path starts with a particular keyword

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am currently using Drupal 7 and I want to restrict blocks for few pages
example:

```
example.com/abcd    
example.com/abcf    
example.com/abch    
example.com/abce/xyz    
I want to hide the block which has the /abc*
```

(where * could be any character after abc).

I have tried it by adding example.com/abc* in visibility setting => restrict to certain pages=> all pages except those listed. This is not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to only add the relative path in the visibility settings and it should work. E.g. just `abc*`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to add each line, no need to add the full url:

abcd
abcf
abch
abce/*

Comment: Thank you for the response.

I have around 100 pages and doing it manually would be very difficult, so is there any other way?